# How to run multiple instances of Firefox independently?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, multiple-instances

There's a web page that generates a  key number for each user, however, you only get a different number using **the same PC** if you use a **different browser**. How could I run multiple instances of Firefox and get multiple keys?

I've tried using multiple tabs, with no success, even when they're detached from one another. Then tried running `firefox -new-instance` , but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You have two obvious options:

1. Use different browsers, it's not that demanding unless you really need a big number of keys.
2. You can open a VM and a Firefox instance in said VM and get a different key. If your system is powerful enough, that could be done as many times as you need quite fast.

Comment: Yes, I need a big number of keys, so the first option wouldn't work that much, but maybe the 2nd  one, I'll search for a way to automate it.